# Add a section widgets dynamically into Card on newSelectionInput OnChangeAction

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I'm trying to add a section widgets dynamically to Card/CardService on  newSelectionInput OnChangeAction, the card already added.

I did not see any documentation on Google, how to achieve this behavior.

Can someone please direct me to the right documentation or how I can do this.

Thanks

Comment: @Cooper Building the gmail addon and writing the code for this in google app script that's why added google script tag, I edited the question is this correct now?

Comment: Once a card is built, I don't think we can update it directly, like adding/removing widgets/sections etc.. We can, however, update it indirectly by first destroying the current card and then updating it.. Refer https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/reference/card-service/navigation#updateCard(Card)

Answer (score -1):

We can add/remove a section from card which is already built in onchange action of input fields.

```js
function getCard(addSection) {

 // this is your function to build the card. The initial "getCard" function call does not have any parameter passed, so it will be treated as "false". Hence no section will be added 

 addSection = addSection || false;
 
 if(addSection) {
 // add your section here
 }
 .....
 return card;
}

function OnChangeAction() {
  var card = getCard(true);
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(card)).build()
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.